# Does garbage collector work on overriden or "nullified" memoized values in javascript?

Tags: javascript, memory, garbage-collection, heap-memory

I am sorry is something similar has been asked, the search didn't find it.

Let's say I have function that creates a big memoized value in js, in the example an array of 1 million random numbers, and call that function twice, so I have two big arrays.

```js
  const memoizedValue = () => {
    const val = [...Array(1000000)].map((_, i) => i + Math.random())
    const valAtIndex = i => val[i];
    return valAtIndex;
  }
  let valAtIndex1 = memoizedValue();
  console.log(valAtIndex1(1000)) // 1000.9215271184725
  console.log(valAtIndex1(1001)) // 1001.123987792151
  let valAtIndex2 = memoizedValue();
  console.log(valAtIndex2(1000)) // 1000.8830808003901
  console.log(valAtIndex2(1001)) // 1001.3989636036797
```

Do I remove the array if I clear a reference to the instance? Does the garbage collector clear the memory for the array if I do this (asuming I don't have any other instance):

```
valAtIndex1 = (i) => i;
console.log(valAtIndex1(1000)) // 1000
console.log(valAtIndex1(1001)) // 1001
```

What if I asign the value `null`, does this clear the memory for the Array?

```
valAtIndex1 = null;
```

Comment: If something is no longer reachable, it's eligible for garbage collection. If you remove the reference to the memoized function, the function can be GCed as would be anything inside, as its no longer reachable from anywhere else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you release all references to the function you've put in `valAtIndex1` (for instance, by doing `valAtIndex1 = x` where `x` can be literally anything as long as it's not the value `valAtIndex1` already has in it — `null`, `undefined`, `42`, ...), that releases that function's reference to the context where it was created, which in turn releases that context's reference to the big array. The garbage collector is free to reclaim that memory.

For example:

```
let valAtIndex = memoizedValue();
console.log(valAtIndex(0)); // 1.3753751200626736 or whatever
valAtIndex = null;          // Releases the reference
```

In the comments you seemed particularly concerned about overwriting the variable's value with the result of another call to `memoizedValue`. That's absolutely fine:

```
let valAtIndex = memoizedValue(); // Creates array A and function A accessing it
console.log(valAtIndex(0));       // 1.3753751200626736 or whatever
valAtIndex = memoizedValue();     // Creates array B and function b accessing it,
                                  // releasing the reference to function A
console.log(valAtIndex(0));       // 1.6239617464592875 or whatever
```

---

Side note: Your code to create the massive array will create an unnecessary temporary massive array (the one you're creating with the array literal), and possibly two of them (the one you're creating with `Array(1000000)` may well reserve memory for all one million array elements; it does in V8, for instance, even though the array is empty). Instead:

```
const val = Array.from({length: 1000000}, (_, i) => i + Math.random());
```

Comment: Thanks, reasigning the value would do the same (as when I override it with a different function), I guess? Is that right?

Comment: @santi - I'm not sure what you mean by "override it with another function." If you change what value `valAtIndex1` contains, then it no longer has its old value (a reference to the function created by `memoizedValue`), and if that old value was the only remaining reference to that function, then the function, the context of the call to `memoizedValue` that created it, and the array that context refers to can all be garbage collected. Again provided it's the only remaining reference.

Comment: By "overriding" I mean change its value to another function (or whatever :-)). Excuse my English...

Comment: @santi - (Don't worry, I think a lot of native speakers would have said exactly the same thing. Your English seems quite good!) If you mean `let valAtIndex1 = memoizedValue(/*...*/); /*...*/ valAtIndex1 = memoizedValue(/*...*/);` ("overwriting"), then yes, the second time you assign to `valAtIndex1` releases the function from the first time. :-) Happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

Assigning the array to `null` `undefined` or `""` will allow it to be cleared by the garbage collector. Javascript does *not* allow you to directly manage the garbage collector in this manner. Just assign it as one of the above values once you're done using it, and it will be cleared automatically for you.

Comment: "*Assigning the array to `null` `undefined` or `""`*" or literally any other value